# Docx4j xhtml-importer support for page-break

Tags: xhtml, docx4j, page-break

Is there a way to create a page break from my html that is readable from docx4j xhtml importer?

Comment: What kind of page break did you have in mind? CSS? `&#12;`?

Comment: Html. When it reads it then it starts the next line in a new page

Answer (score 0):

Did you try CSS **page-break-before: always**?